# Scrape Company opening amd closing time on Google map

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, data-mining

I am trying to get Google Maps Company's opening and closing times with selenium python.

**An example link is given bellow :**

> https://www.google.com/maps/place/Solar+Project+Development+%26+Engineering+Ltd./@23.7988032,90.3525855,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x3755c181e4e00229:0xa17c29dbd5a924f6!8m2!3d23.7988032!4d90.3525855!16s%2Fg%2F11q41jstmd?authuser=0&hl=en&entry=ttu

**Here is my code :**

```
class GoogleMapScraperInformation:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.headless = False
        self.driver = None 


    def config_driver(self):
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

        s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
        self.driver = driver


    def get_info(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)


        try:
            companey_name = self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "lfPIob").text
        except:
            companey_name = ''
        # print(companey_name,"***********")
        
        try:
            address = self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "kR99db").text
        except:
            address = ''
        # print(address,"***********")
```

**I also one step scroll down but I did not find it .**

```
    image_element = self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "lvtCsd img")
    img_result = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[7]/div[5]/a/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]')))
    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",img_result)
```

**I want to click here :**

[image]

**and after that, I want to get all the opening and closing time**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is the problem here.

It can be easily got by clicking on open dropdown icon and waiting for element with `aria-label` that contains any of week days.

Then you can parse data by your needs.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/place/Solar+Project+Development+%26+Engineering+Ltd./@23.7988032,90.3525855,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x3755c181e4e00229:0xa17c29dbd5a924f6!8m2!3d23.7988032!4d90.3525855!16s%2Fg%2F11q41jstmd?authuser=0&hl=en&entry=ttu")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[role=button] [role=img]"))).click()
close_open_el = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[aria-label*=Thursday]")))

print(close_open_el.text)
```

Comment: but this is not working for this link ->   https://www.google.com/maps/place/Solar+Project+Development+%26+Engineering+Ltd./@23.7988032,90.3525855,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x3755c181e4e00229:0xa17c29dbd5a924f6!8m2!3d23.7988032!4d90.3525855!16s%2Fg%2F11q41jstmd?authuser=0&hl=en&entry=ttu

Comment: @Tusher it's working for this link. Proof: https://monosnap.com/file/rtZtQTnoQXaaX6cM0A4xfD3p2fJgxv